# REGEX - How to check for a group of words sentence by sentence?

Tags: regex, pcre

My task is to check the existence of specific words in sentences from a file. The file is huge so I have included just a small portion below that is giving me an issue.

> Important COVID-19 travel guidance
>
> The Foreign, Commonwealth &
> Development Office currently advises British nationals against all but
> essential international travel. Travel to some countries and
> territories is currently exempted.
>
> This advice is being kept under constant review. Travel disruption is
> still possible and national control measures may be brought in with
> little notice, so check our travel guidance.

I need to check if all these words `advise`, `against`, `all`, `travel`, and `to` are in any single sentence of this text. The words need to be in this order, but other words can fall in between them. I am using PHP so I need a PCRE compatible regex.

So far I've managed to match all the words by using `/advise.*against.*all.*travel.*to/i` but this regex is looking through all the text (not just sentence by sentence) as can be seen [here](https://regex101.com/r/5EpAYQ/2)

In this above text portion I expect this regex to not match anything because not all the words are present in any single sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using greedy quantifiers (`*`) on a wildcard (`.`), so it is searching way beyond just a sentence since it doesn't know when to stop. You need to tell your regex to only look for a sentence. The easiest way to do this is to tell it what ends a sentence. You probably don't want a wildcard (`.`) but rather anything that is not sentence ending punctuation.

Instead of `.*` maybe try something along the lines of `[^.!?]*` or `[\w\d\s,;:]*` depending on what you want to consider a sentence.

[Try it out!](https://regex101.com/r/DVCju4/1)